# Only Date Part comparison with System Date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure :-

```
CREATE procedure St_Proc_GetTimeEntryID            
@userID int,            
@timeEntryID int output            
as begin             
    set nocount on;      
    SET @timeEntryID=0      
    DECLARE @TEMP INT       
    SET @TEMP=0        
    SELECT @TEMP=ProductionTimeEntryID            
    FROM    production            
    WHERE   ProductionTimeEntryID =             
        (SELECT MAX(ProductionTimeEntryID)             
            FROM production            
            where UserID=@userID             
            and (CalendarDate = (select GETDATE()))            
            and IsTaskCompleted=1 )      
            BEGIN      
                SET @timeEntryID=@TEMP      
            END      
END
```

Here CalendarDate is column which containing Date As 06/26/201212:00PM format .
I want to compare the date part only with system date part  (06/26/2012 = 06/26/2012) in my subquery which is

```
(SELECT MAX(ProductionTimeEntryID)             
            FROM production            
            where UserID=@userID 
            and (CalendarDate = (select GETDATE()))            
            and IsTaskCompleted=1 )
```

Please guide me what modification i ll do to get the result.

Comment: Is the `CalendarDate` column `DATETIME` or something else? For clarity it's important to state the data type and also to understand that a `DATETIME` data type does not store any format as you suggest - that's just how Management Studio displays it to you, based on the regional settings of the machine, your language settings, etc. Specifying SQL Server version is also helpful.

Comment: The CalendarDate column is DATETIME and I m using Sql Server 2008 .Your comments helped me and next time i ll really specify all these points if trapped in any issue. Thanks for the Suggestion @Aoron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient method (meaning fully able to utilize an index on `CalendarDate`, if one exists) is going to be, on SQL Server 2000/2005:

```
DECLARE @today SMALLDATETIME;
SET @today = DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

...
WHERE CalendarDate >= @today
AND CalendarDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @today);
```

If using SQL Server 2008+:

```
DECLARE @today DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
...
WHERE CalendarDate >= @today
AND CalendarDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @today);
```

You can also use a direct cast in SQL Server 2008+, but I'm not 100% sure this is guaranteed to use an index on `CalendarDate` in all scenarios:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, CalendarDate) = CONVERT(DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Because this casting does not work with other date/time data types, for consistency I much prefer the open-ended range technique, and definitely do not condone most of the scenarios where you perform implicit or explicit conversions on the column (since this usually means an index won't be used). I've ranted about this and several other date/time atrocities plenty at the following blog posts:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Answer (score 2):

In SQL2K8;

```
 ... WHERE CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE) <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

(This will negate any index use on `CalendarDate`, alternatively bracket `CalendarDate` between `CalendarDate >= CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE) AND < DATEADD(...`)

Comment: Actually this is one of the exceptions, where SQL Server does still choose to use an index even if you've converted the column to DATE. But because this is not documented (at least that I've found), because there may be exceptions outside of my test cases, and because it doesn't work with other date/time data types, I still prefer the >= & < format.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
(SELECT MAX(ProductionTimeEntryID)             
        FROM production            
        where UserID=412             
        and (convert(datetime, convert(varchar(100), CalendarDate, 106)) <= convert(datetime, convert(varchar(100), GETDATE(), 106)))            
        and IsTaskCompleted=1 )
```

Comment: In SQL2008R2, you can also use: `and CAST( CalendarDate AS DATE ) <= CAST( GETDATE() AS DATE )`

Comment: @SeanW Your comment is much better than the answer. At least that still has some chance to use an index. Your answer suggests four wasteful conversions.

Comment: yep - that was how i used to do it pre-2008... old habits :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [convert function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

In your case:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),101)
```

More specifically:

```
(SELECT MAX(ProductionTimeEntryID)             
            FROM production            
            where UserID=@userID 
            and (CONVERT(DATE,CalendarDate) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))            
            and IsTaskCompleted=1 )
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand - for comparison its not required though OP specified it like this `06/26/2012 = 06/26/2012` i.e. Month/Day/Year

Comment: Did the OP say the data was stored as a string? My suspicion is this is just what Management Studio shows him.

Comment: Well, you are right Aaron. If you would, you can edit the answer to improve the quality.